# WatchKit, stop the user tapping back

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

in my watchOS app, when I navigate to a different view controller I want to stop the user from hitting the back arrow. How do I disable this?

My app is in Swift, or is this an xcode problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you use modal navigation by calling presentControllerWithname to navigate to your interface controller, you won't be able to disable the cancel button.
However, by changing your interface controller to root controller, you can get rid of the cancel button.

```
  WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["NewInterfaceController"], contexts: ["NewInterfaceController"])
```